# How can I plot this using plt.semilogy() in pandas?

Tags: pandas

```
x = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.title_year, [1916,2016]))['gross'].sum()
y = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.title_year, [1916,2016]))['gross'].mean()
print(x,y)

plt.semilogy(x,y)
```

This code finds the sum of total income and average income from the year 1916-2016. How can I plot this using the `plt.semilogy()`? I've tried `plt.semilogy(x,y)` but the group doesn't plot.

[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTELP.png).

Comment: You're trying to plot a line through a single point, what do you expect it to look like?

Comment: I'm not so sure what the graph will look like. I'm trying to construct a plot that relates release years to total income and average income for that year. I'm not sure if my code does this, but I think it should look like a log graph

Comment: @gereleth any suggestions?

Comment: I can't understand if you want data for every year from 1916 to 2016 (in that case you're doing the grouping wrong) or just two numbers x and y for the entire years range (that looks like what you're calculating). You can add a linestyle to the plot command so that you'll see this single point: `plt.semilogy(x,y,'-o')`

Comment: Ya. I wanted it for every year from 1916 to 2016. How Can I fix my code? @gereleth

Comment: I gaze into my crystal ball and I see... `groupby('title_year')`

Comment: x = df.groupby(pd.cut('title_year', [1916,2016]))['gross'].sum()
Likt this? @gereleth

Comment: Giving me error with if its like that...

Comment: Try `x = df.groupby('title_year')['gross'].sum()`. If that doesn't work for you consider asking another question with some example data and expected output.

Comment: @gereleth ohhhh one last question, those data it shows are sum and average for that current year for every years?

Comment: https://snag.gy/EYozm9.jpg here's the output. There are some NaN in some of the years. Is that why the graph looks not so neat?